# IDE does not recognize Assumptions

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit, junit-jupiter

I am using **Junit5**, and my **IDE (IntelijIdea)** is not recognize **Assumptions**. I am actually do not know why, but may be there is some dependecy on Maven I do not connect into project. Below I will show you the sample of my code.

This is my Assumptions import.

`import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assumptions;`

And this is wrong code (I can not compile it, compiler does not know what is assumeTrue() )

```
@Test
@EnabledOnOs(OS.MAC)
void testInsertion() {
    assumeTrue(isServerUp); //That place is crashing
    assertThrows(NullPointerException.class, () -> Connection.insertTheInstance(person),
            "");
```

If you are familiar with this case then, please, share you knowledge) Many thanks!

Comment: JUnit 5 consists of several modules and assumptions are a part of `junit-jupiter-api` library, so you need this dependency in your pom file, e.g. the latest stable version is [5.6.2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api/5.6.2)

Comment: Can you compile project from command line by Maven?

Comment: No, I have tried)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a import problem probably. Try:

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
     <version>5.6.2</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
```

- Check if maven import is ok
- Close your project in intellij
- Delete your .m2 folder in your HOME directory (user/yourusername in windows, /home in linux)
- Execute in a terminal in your project: mvn dependency:purge-local-repository clean.
- Open your project again

If it's not ok yet, try the junit 4.12. Its have Assumptions too.

Answer (score 0):

assumeTrue method is part of JUnit 4, but you can also use it in JUnit 5 through the

> org.junit.jupiter.api.Assumptions class.

For intelliJ - Junit5 combination, make sure to import the following in your class:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assumptions.assumeTrue;
```